# Stack overflow when testing a function passed to a widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I made a small app to test passing a function to a widget, I have no compile errors, however, when I run that app, I see 45 times the call to `buildSwitchListTile`.

I don't understand why it's being called so many times. I am running latest versions for VSCode, Flutter, and Dart.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './widgets/build_switch_list_tile.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Function to Widget'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _option1 = false;
  bool _option2 = true;
  bool _option3 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            // use widget here
            buildSwitchListTile(
              'Option 1',
              'From widget Select option 1',
              _option1,
              (newValue) {
                if (newValue != _option1) {
                  setState(() {
                    _option1 = newValue;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            // end test widget

            buildSwitchListTile(
              'Option 2',
              'From widget Select option 2',
              _option2,
              (newValue) {
                if (newValue != _option2) {
                  setState(() {
                    _option2 = newValue;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),

            buildSwitchListTile(
              'Option 3',
              'From widget Select option 3',
              _option3,
              (newValue) {
                if (newValue != _option3) {
                  setState(() {
                    _option3 = newValue;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget buildSwitchListTile(
  String title,
  String description,
  bool currentValue,
  void Function(bool)? updateValue,
) {
  return buildSwitchListTile(
    title,
    description,
    currentValue,
    updateValue,
  );
}
```

I try to avoid calling `setState` if the switch is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting error is because you are calling buildSwitchListTile inside buildSwitchListTile. This will make the method call itself recursively forever until the app crash.

If you are trying to add a SwitchListTile widget in your app, probably you would want to add SwitchListTile (without the "build"). Then your method will be something like this:

```dart
Widget buildSwitchListTile(
  String title,
  String description,
  bool currentValue,
  void Function(bool)? updateValue,
) {
  return SwitchListTile(
    title: Column(
      children: [
        Text(title),
        Text(description),
      ],
    ),
    value: currentValue,
    onChanged: updateValue,
  );
}
```

For more information check the [API documentation of the SwitchListTile widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile-class.html).

*Note: it's better to create a custom widget to wrap that code and not just use a helper method, as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOyq-eTRhvo) from the Flutter YouTube channel*

Comment: Many thanks Samuel for your answer. My big mistake, I was so obsessed by the function that I completely miss the stupid logical error.